# Pre-processor directive in Go like in C

Tags: go, preprocessor-directive

I am a novice to Go and wanted to know whether Go has pre-processor directives like in C.

Go has `nil` which is similar to `null` in other languages.

As `null` has been extensively used I do not want to use `nil`.

So, I was expecting a define statement (a pre-processor directive) in Go language to do like the following:

```
define nil null
```

Is there any implementation like that?

Comment: ‘_I do not want to use `nil`_’ Then find an other language. Go uses `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, a powerful language with  a skewed syntax

Answer (score -1):

Macros in Go are constants. They do the same thing.

```
#define A 96
```

in C is the same as:

```
const A = 96
```

in Go.

But const in Go is way less flexible than C macros and I think there's no way of using null instead of nil.